# Add git hook to watch for files' changes

Tags: git, githooks, npm-shrinkwrap

I am trying to create a git hook that evaluate the package.json for changes and auto-runs the shrinkwrapper and commits the changed file to a repository. I have tried a lot, but could not get a working solution. Does anyone know how do that ?

Also, whenever I add a npm module, and try to run npm shrinkwrap, I get this error

```
 npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "shrinkwrap"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Problems were encountered
npm ERR! Please correct and try again.
npm ERR! missing: request-promise@^4.2.2, required by Redux-React@1.0.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/maxDoung/Desktop/Redux-React/npm-debug.log
```

for some reason npm shrink does not work if I update package.json manually or install a module using npm. Also, I am not sure if the node or npm version matters. I am using npm 3.10.10, and node v6.11.3

Here is my dependency

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apn": "^1.7.7",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "busboy": "^0.2.13",
    "connect-redis": "^3.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "destroy": "^1.0.4",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "git-rev": "^0.2.1",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "helmet": "^1.3.0",
    "hiredis": "^0.4.1",
    "humps": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.14.1",
    "methods": "^1.1.2",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1",
    "node-gcm": "^0.14.4",
    "node-inspector": "^0.12.8",
    "node-resource": "^1.2.0",
    "on-finished": "^2.3.0",
    "on-headers": "^1.0.1",
    "parseurl": "^1.3.1",
    "path-to-regexp": "^1.5.3",
    "redis": "^2.6.0-0",
    "request": "^2.69.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.23.6",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.6",
    "through2": "^2.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: Can you please show the folder structure of your repository, mainly the part relevant to `npm shrinkwrap`?

Comment: Do you want to evaluate on every commit in the push or only for every push?

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is what you want or at least it will point you to the right direction. I've tested this on Linux.

**Please follow these steps (adapt them as your specific needs):**

1 - Put the following file at **.git/hooks/pre-commit**:

```
#!/bin/bash

is_package_json_at_git_index() {
  echo "> Getting list of files at git index."

  # Get the list of files added to the git index and verify that package.json is there.
  git diff --cached --name-only | grep -x package.json
}

update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index() {
  echo "> Updating npm-shrinkwrap.json and adding to this commit."

  # Run shrinkwrap in the case that it was never ran
  npm shrinkwrap

  # Install dependencies that could be added to package.json and update npm-shrinkwrap.json
  npm install

  # Add the updated- npm-shrinkwrap.json to the git index so we include it in the current commit
  git add npm-shrinkwrap.json 
}

if is_package_json_at_git_index; then
  update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index
fi
```

2 - Add run permissions to the pre-commit
`chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit`

**Now, if you do the following:**

1. You update manually package.json maybe updating a version of a dependency.
2. You run `git add package.json`
3. You run `git commit -m "Your commit message"`

**The following will happen:**

1. npm-shrinkwrap.json will be updated
2. npm-shrinkwrap.json will be automatically added to the commit

**NOTE:** You could use other hooks, please take a look at a detailed explanation of them [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your answer. It does not work if you update the package.json manually; for example if you add "request-promise": "^4.2.2" to package.json, then try to commit. You will get an error saying that request-promise is missing. Your solution works fine if you use npm install but not manually. Is there a solution that allows updating package.json manually ?

Comment: @MaxDoung, I've tested with npm 5.3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 and works fine doing the following: 1. I edited package.json and added  "request-promise": "^4.2.2" to the dependencies section. 2. git add package.json, 3. git commit -m "Added request-promise dependency". After this, the npm-shrinkwrap.json has all the changes commited to the repository along with the updated package.json.

Comment: @MaxDoung Can you try to run my example with npm 5.3.0?

Comment: I tired now and I keep getting
npm ERR! Problems were encountered
npm ERR! Please correct and try again.
npm ERR! missing: request-promise@^4.2.2, required by Redux-React@1.0.0. I am not sure where the problem is. I am using npm 3.10.10 which should be fine

Comment: @MaxDoung, Sure, the problem that you are having is with the dependencies resolution, it could actually be a bug with npm shrinkwrap, you have to debug it further but this is not related with git hooks.